# Graphql embedded arrays are null in Java mutation

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

We are using spring boot v2.6.8, graphql v12.0.0,  graphql java tools v12.0.0 and java v1.8.

When using graphql mutation with an input object that contains arrays, and those arrays are defined in the graphql schema, I expect to be able to unpack those arrays within Java.  There are no error messages or warning, but the resulting arrays are all null.

We have verified that the json payload contains the correct structure and data.

Below is a simple example of what we are attempting to do.

**project.qraphqls**

```
type Mutation {
   saveClass(input: ClassInput) :Class!
}

input ClassInput {
    id: ID
    label: String
    ClassroomInput: [ClassroomInput] 
    StudentInput: [IdentifierInput]
}

input ClassroomInput {
    id: ID
    location: String!
}

input IdentifierInput {
    id: Int!
}
```

**Sample Java Code**

```
@Component
public class ClassInput implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2457023600132718516L;
    private Long id;
    private String label = "";
    private List<ClassroomInput> classroomInput;
    private List<IdentifierInput> studentInput;

    public ClassInput() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public List<ClassroomInput> getClassroomInput() {
        return classroomInput;
    }

    public void setClassroomInput(List<ClassroomInput> ClassroomInput) {
        this.classroomInput = ClassroomInput;
    }

    public List<IdentifierInput> getStudentInput() {
        return studentInput;
    }

    public void setStudentInput(List<IdentifierInput> namesInput) {
        this. studentInput = namesInput;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class IdentifierInput implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3366236968099057715L;

    private Long id;

    public IdentifierInput() {
        
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class ClassroomInput implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7209564661197261261L;
    private Long id;
    private String location = "";

    public ClassroomInput() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class ClassMutation implements GraphQLMutationResolver 
{
  final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassMutation.class);

    public Class saveClass(ClassInput input) 
    {   
        logger.info("**** input label: "+input.getLabel());
        if(input.getClassroomInput() == null) {
            logger.info("**** input location was null ");
        } else {
            logger.info("**** input location size: "+input.getClassroomInput().size());
        }
        if(input.getStudentInput() == null) {
            logger.info("**** input student was null ");
        } else {
            logger.info("**** input student size: "+input.getStudentInput().size());
        }

        // Other business logic
}
```

Can graphql inputs have embedded arrays just like types do? Is there different syntax?